# FBSDKBasicUtility array:addObject: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x107c269a0"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have Integrated facebook SDK in unity. Its works fine for android but when i move it to XCode for IOS built it making issues.

Error: `First RegisterMonoModules.h file not find`

Solution: I make empty file at unity backend. Then also added this file in XCode libraries. Issues Resolved.

This thing created the build for IOS but app crashes each time on Starting Game. And error appears on XCode: `Exception: "+[FBSDKBasicUtility array:addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x107c269a0"`

Then again digging, i found its a linking issue: I add Other Linking flags: `-ObjC, -force_load, ${PROJECT_DIR}/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit , ${PROJECT_DIR}/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit , -all_load`

But Still this thing not working. Exception remains same. app crashes on Start.

Unity Version: `2019.3.7f1`
Facebook SDK Version: `7.16.1`

Answer (score 0):

what's work for me, I go to unity project and I delete play-services-resolver under Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor and build again